# How to add Pagination to a custom made page in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I wanted to limit the page with 10 records, i tried with this https://dolphinwebsolution.com/magento-2-add-pagination-in-custom-collection-of
But it didn't worked for me,
I anyone has some other suggestions please let me know.
This is my code for the quote page .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDDCY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL3Qd.png)

Comment: Can you please provide more information of the files you are using? because you are only showing the phtml and the issue might be in the getCustomData data, the collection might be fetched wrong,etc

A good teardown of the files that you are using are much more appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have solved the issue by applying a code to fetch data collection and bind it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding a modified prepare layout in the block code.
here i'm attaching the code.

```
enter code here  protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Quote'));
    if ($this->getSavedQuotes()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager'
        )->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10,20=>20,30=>30))->setShowPerPage(false)->setCollection($this->getSavedQuotes());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getSavedQuotes()->load();
    }
    return $this;
}
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}

public function getSavedQuotes()
{
    $page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    $pageSize = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 10;
    return $this->_quoteMainFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter(
            'is_deleted', 0
        )->addFieldToFilter(
            'status', 1
        )->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId())->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($page);;
}
```